# The argument type 'RefreshConfiguration Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)

Tags: dart

i try create:()=> nothing changed the same issue still , what i should do?

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ScreenUtilInit(
designSize: const Size(360, 640),
minTextAdapt: true,
splitScreenMode: true,
builder: (context) => RefreshConfiguration(
headerBuilder: () => const WaterDropHeader(),
footerBuilder: () => const ClassicFooter(),
headerTriggerDistance: 30.0,
springDescription:
const SpringDescription(stiffness: 170, damping: 16, mass: 1.9),
maxOverScrollExtent: 30,
maxUnderScrollExtent: 0,
enableScrollWhenRefreshCompleted: true,
enableLoadingWhenFailed: true,
hideFooterWhenNotFull: false,
enableBallisticLoad: true,
child: MaterialApp(
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? widget) {
return MediaQuery(
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
child: widget!,
);
},
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'Quran Karim ',
initialRoute: CacheHelper.getBooleanData(key: isCachingQuran) == false
? WelcomeView.id
: HomeView.id,
routes: Routes.routes,
localizationsDelegates: translator.delegates,
locale: translator.activeLocale,
supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
darkTheme: AppTheme.dartTheme,
themeMode:
AppThemeProvider().isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
),
),
);
}
}

i try create same proplim